# How to forbid my location only for Viber on my Android phone?

Tags: applications, viber-messenger, location-services

I want to know how can I switch off the location service ONLY for Viber on my Android phone. I know there is an option to do that on iOS, but is there any way to do it on Android phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, when you get an android phone out of the box, no, there is no way to do that.

However, if you're willing to root your phone, then you can use apps like "Apps Ops Starter" which essentially launch the hidden settings for you to use which would allow you to find Viber (or any other app) and see its permissions and deny them one by one.

Comment: Hi Todd, Thank you for the answer and the suggestion. However, my phone is few months old and still in its warranty period so I don't feel brave enough to root it :-).

Comment: Ah. Yea... That's the bad part about that. You can try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.slvn.appops&hl=en ... that might work. I'm not sure because I haven't used it, but it doesn't state anything about needing root.

Comment: "App Ops" starters usually don't need root, so this should work – depending on the Android version. "App Ops" where introduced with 4.2 AFAIK, and are no longer available with 4.4.2 and up – so the window is small.

Comment: Thanks @Izzy, I had a look at this app and is seems to be exactly what I want, but as I'm with Android 4.2.2 it won't work on my phone :-(

Comment: Alternative options come up if your device is rooted. Is it?

Comment: @Izzy, no it is not, and I'm still not sure if I want to root it or not.

Comment: @RamzyShah Without root, I'm not aware of any working alternative. So while thinking about "to root or not to root": put this argument on the "pro-root" side...